# Winapi: Screenshot is not displayed on window

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, window

I'm new with GUI programming on windows and came across some problems (using visual studio 2017).

I have a client and server application, client basically takes pictures of desktop and sends it to server which then displays it on the screen. As I decided to post a question here I created one project which creates a window(which is used to display screensots) takes the screenshot and displays it (I tried to use as minimal code as possible to reproduce the problem).

Here is the code:

```
// Onefile.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <Windowsx.h>
#include <WinSock.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <Stdio.h>
#include <Security.h>
#include <Sddl.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <Urlmon.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32")

static BITMAPINFO g_bmpInfo;
static BYTE      *g_pixels = NULL;
HWND hWndClient;
HDC hDcBmpServer;
static const TCHAR *className = TEXT("ControlWindow");
static const TCHAR *titlePattern = TEXT("Desktop");

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
  case WM_CREATE:
  {
    printf("WndProc: WM_CREATE\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    break;
  }
  case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
  {
    printf("WndProc: WM_SYSCOMMAND\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  case WM_PAINT:
  {
    printf("WndProc: WM_PAINT\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC         hDc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    if (hDc == NULL)
    {
      printf("WM_PAINT: BeginPaint FAILED!\n");
      fflush(stdout);
    }

    RECT clientRect;
    if (GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRect) == 0)
    {
      printf("WM_PAINT: GetClientRect FAILED %d\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stdout);
    }

    RECT rect;
    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));

    if (hBrush == NULL)
    {
      printf("%d WM_PAINT: CreateSolidBrush FAILED %d\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stdout);
    }

    rect.left = 0;
    rect.top = 0;
    rect.right = clientRect.right;
    rect.bottom = clientRect.bottom;

    rect.left = g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth;


    if (FillRect(hDc, &rect, hBrush) == 0)
    {
      printf("WM_PAINT: FillRect 1.0 failed!\n");
      fflush(stdout);
    }

    rect.left = 0;
    rect.top = g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight;


    if (FillRect(hDc, &rect, hBrush) == 0)
    {
      printf("WM_PAINT: FillRect 2.0 failed!\n");
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    DeleteObject(hBrush);

    if (BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, hDcBmpServer, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) == 0)
    {
      printf("WM_PAINT: BitBlt failed!%d\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("WM_PAINT: BitBl SUCCESS!\n");
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
  }
  case WM_DESTROY:
  {
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
  }
  case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    return TRUE;
  case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
  case WM_LBUTTONUP:
  case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
  case WM_RBUTTONUP:
  case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
  case WM_MBUTTONUP:
  case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
  case WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK:
  case WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK:
  case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
  case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
  {
    printf("WndProc: Buttons\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    break;
  }
  case WM_CHAR:
  {
    printf("WndProc: WM_char\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    break;
  }
  case WM_KEYDOWN:
  case WM_KEYUP:
  {
    printf("WndProc: KEYUPm\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case VK_UP:
    case VK_DOWN:
    case VK_RIGHT:
    case VK_LEFT:
    case VK_HOME:
    case VK_END:
    case VK_PRIOR:
    case VK_NEXT:
    case VK_INSERT:
    case VK_RETURN:
    case VK_DELETE:
    case VK_BACK:
      break;
    }
  }
  case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
  {
    printf("WndProc: WM_GETMINMAXINFO\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    break;
  }
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
return 0;
}

//Register class
BOOL CW_Register(WNDPROC lpfnWndProc)
{
  WNDCLASSEX wndClass;
  wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
  wndClass.lpfnWndProc = lpfnWndProc;
  wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
  wndClass.hInstance = NULL;
  wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
  wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
  wndClass.lpszClassName = className;
  wndClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  return RegisterClassEx(&wndClass);
}

//Create window which should display pictures
HWND CW_Create()
{
  printf("CW_Create: Creating Windows...\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  hWndClient = CreateWindow(className,
    titlePattern,
    WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    800,
    600,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);

  if (hWndClient == NULL)
  {
    printf("CW_Create:  ERROR! CreateWindow failed %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    return NULL;
  }

  if (ShowWindow(hWndClient, SW_SHOW) == 0)
  {
    printf("CW_Create: The window was previously hidden\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("CW_Create: The window was previously shown\n");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  printf("CW_Create: Exiting...\n");
  return hWndClient;
}


void CreateWindows()
{
  CW_Register(WndProc);
  CW_Create();
}

int main()
{
  CreateWindows();

  memset(&g_bmpInfo, 0, sizeof(g_bmpInfo));

  g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader);
  g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
  g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
  g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
  g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
  g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 800 * 3 * 600;

  //Client side which takes a picture of screen
  RECT rect;
  HWND hWndDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
  GetWindowRect(hWndDesktop, &rect);

  HDC     hDc = GetDC(NULL);

  if(hDc == NULL)
  {
    printf("Client: hDc is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }
  HDC     hDcScreen = CreateCompatibleDC(hDc);

  if (hDcScreen == NULL)
  {
    printf("Client: hDcScreen is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }

  HBITMAP hBmpScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDc, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);

  if (hBmpScreen == NULL)
  {
    printf("Client: hBmpScreen is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }

  //Resize the picture to 800x600 dimension
  HBITMAP hBmpScreenResized = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDc, 800, 600);

  if (hBmpScreenResized == NULL)
  {
    printf("Client: hBmpScreenResized is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }
  HDC     hDcScreenResized = CreateCompatibleDC(hDc);

  if (hDcScreenResized == NULL)
  {
    printf("Client: hDcScreenResized is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }

  SelectObject(hDcScreenResized, hBmpScreenResized);

  SetStretchBltMode(hDcScreenResized, HALFTONE);
  if (StretchBlt(hDcScreenResized, 0, 0, 800, 600,
    hDcScreen, 0, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, SRCCOPY) == 0)
  {
    printf("Client: StretchBlt is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }

  DeleteObject(hBmpScreen);
  DeleteDC(hDcScreen);

  //Assign new values
  hBmpScreen = hBmpScreenResized;
  hDcScreen = hDcScreenResized;

  SelectObject(hDcScreen, hBmpScreen);

  free((HLOCAL)g_pixels);

  g_pixels = (BYTE *)malloc(g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);

  g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = 800;
  g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = 600;

  if (GetDIBits(hDcScreen, hBmpScreen, 0, 600, g_pixels, &g_bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS) == 0)
  {
    printf("Client: GetDIBits is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }

  DeleteObject(hBmpScreen);
  ReleaseDC(NULL, hDc);
  DeleteDC(hDcScreen);


  //Server side which should take the pixels and paint them on the window
  HDC hDcServer = GetDC(NULL);
  if (hDcServer == NULL)
  {
    printf("Server: hDcServer is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }

  hDcBmpServer = CreateCompatibleDC(hDcServer);
  HBITMAP hBmp;

  hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDcServer, g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight);
  if (hBmp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Server: hBmp is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }

  SelectObject(hDcBmpServer, hBmp);

  int ScanLines = SetDIBits(hDcBmpServer,
    hBmp,
    0,
    g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight,
    g_pixels,
    &g_bmpInfo,
    DIB_RGB_COLORS);

  if (ScanLines == 0)
  {
    printf("Server: hBmp is NULL %d\n", GetLastError());
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Server: Scanned lines %d\n", ScanLines);
  }

  fflush(stdout);

  InvalidateRgn(hWndClient, NULL, TRUE);

  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
  {
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm creating a window using `CreateWindows` function, then try to take a screenshot, then I resize it to the proper window size
which in my case is `800x600` and then try to display it using `InvalidateRgn` function. I've deleted basically all code in `WndProc` in sake of this question and only left `WM_PAINT` part.

The problem I'm having is that the window which should be filled with the screenshot is black and nothing is displayed on it. I have no compiler or runtime errors but the screenshot is not displayed. I think I'm missing some information on how to do this properly. Hope you can help.

**P.S**

This is the source code of some project, I don't want to convert screenshot into `.bmp` and send it that way, I want to understand why this method doesn't work. thanks.

Comment: My bad, I changed it to `rect.left = clientRect.left;` since I use `GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRect)` but I have same situation.

Comment: Your program has nothing to do with client/server. This is a stand alone program, it's a good start to get the functions right before moving to client/server. Please describe what you are trying to do within the context of a stand alone program. Note, `WndProc` should return 0 if `swich` statement break.

Comment: thanks for the note, I want to take a screenshot and display it on the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a memory device context and bitmap (`HBITMAP` handle). Select the bitmap in to memory dc. Then use `BitBlt` to copy from screen to memory dc. The bitmap will then contain the screen data.

You can then print the bitmap handle directly in `WM_PAINT`. This would be a DDB, it can't be transferred between programs. You need DIB, or so use `GetDIBits` to copy the content from bitmap in to a byte array (`g_bmpInfo` and `g_pixels`)

Note that the size of 24-bit bitmap is not always `with * height * 3`, you need a special formula to account for padding.

```
BITMAPINFO g_bmpInfo;
BYTE      *g_pixels = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        auto hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);

        int w = g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth;
        int h = g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight;
        if(g_pixels && w && h)
        {
            //print the bitmap on screen
            SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, 0, h, g_pixels,
                 &g_bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        }

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    CreateWindows();

    RECT rect;
    HWND hWndDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    GetWindowRect(hWndDesktop, &rect);
    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    int bpp = 24; //24-bit
    int size = ((width * bpp + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

    memset(&g_bmpInfo, 0, sizeof(g_bmpInfo));
    g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader);
    g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    g_bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = size;

    g_pixels = new BYTE[size];

    auto hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    auto memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    auto hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
    auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

    //copy from screen to memory    
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //fill g_pixels array
    GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, height, g_pixels, &g_bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    //cleanup    
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);

    delete[] g_pixels;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanaition. Just to be sure, sending `g_pixels` and `g_bmpInfo` from client to server, then calling `SetDIBitsToDevice` on server side should display the image right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to send `g_pixels` and `&g_bmpInfo` as binary data.

Comment: and one more question please, We create bitmap of entire screen in here `CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);`,but it shrinks to window size(800x600), I added this code https://pastebin.com/MaFrbZVh but the image is same in the window. Should `StretchBlt` function "stretch" entire screen bitmap into `800x600` bitmap? P.S I'm trying to have whole screen image in the window not part of it.

Comment: Maybe system DPI settings is at 125% or higher. Call `SetProcessDPIAware()` at the start of the program. Ideally DPI awareness should be set in manifest file. See also [High DPI in Desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)